# Python Regex replace multiple occurencies of parts of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a chunk of HTML that contains multiple `<img>` tags. The current format of the tag is:

```
<img width="580" height="183" src="/images/stories/acidalkalinetable.jpg" alt="acid alkaline table" title="Body pH Balance">
```

I want to go through the html and for each `<img>` tag change the format to:

```
<img width="580" height="183" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/acidalkalinetable.jpg"}}" alt="acid alkaline table" title="Body pH Balance">
```

You can see it's the `src` that's changing. I've kept the filename but changed other parts of the `src`

If the img was a single string I could do something like:

```
content = '<img width="580" height="183" src="/images/stories/acidalkalinetable.jpg" alt="acid alkaline table" title="Body pH Balance">'

filename = re.search(r'/images/stories/\w+\.(jpg|png|gif)', content)

new_content = re.sub(r'/images/stories/\w+\.(jpg|png|gif)', '{{media url="wysiwyg/' + filename + '"}}', content)
```

(I haven't tested that)

But I'm not sure how I can do that for each occurrence of the `<img>` tag in HTML

Comment: Are you sure about the quoting? `"{{media url="wysiwyg/acidalkalinetable.jpg"}}"`, the wsiwyg part is outside the quote.

Comment: Yeah, I'm cleaning up the data to import into Magento. That's how it does it's image tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the filename as a group, you can then replace it in one go:

```
re.sub(r'/images/stories/([\w%]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))', r'{{media url="wysiwyg/\1"}}', content)
```

This puts a capturing group (`(...)`) around the whole filename including the extension (itself now using a *non*-capturing `(?:...)` group instead), resulting in:

```
>>> re.sub(r'/images/stories/([\w%]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))', r'{{media url="wysiwyg/\1"}}', content)
'<img width="580" height="183" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/acidalkalinetable.jpg"}}" alt="acid alkaline table" title="Body pH Balance">'
```

This uses `\1` as a replacement pattern, see the [`re.sub()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

This `re.sub()` call will replace *all* matching `/images/stories/..` paths with the `{{media url="wisywig/.."}}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to update the regex so that is can handle possible spaces in filename ie something%20something.jpg

Comment: @iamjonesy: done; all you needed to do was extend the `\w` to a characterclass that adds `%` as an option.